# GnuRadio w/ LimeSDR IQ Splitter Phase Shift

Tags: signals, gnuradio, software-defined-radio, iq

The following flowgraph implements an IQ splitter. My doubt lies on the complex to float block, where Real and Imag parts of the signal are splitted and given as output. Mathematically, do they represent the IN Phase and Quadrature versions of the signal? When I scope them they only show in-phase component in constellation sink, although in time scope, they actually seem to have a 90º difference.

So, in the output of the LimeSDR in MIMO mode (Tx1 and TX2 in use), both signals will pass through a complex mixer, will I really have these two versions as I and Q signals separatedly?

I need to separate them because the input of an UP/DOWN converter I am connecting to the SDR output/input needs I and Q as 2 different inputs/outputs.

Seems strange, but basically I have to build an IQ signal and in order to be able to upconvert, I need to split it, as the connected hardware will mix them up. The inverse process will be handed over on the Rx side.

Flowgraph:

[image: Flowgraph]